# Raymarching - Artifacts when rendering 3D texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, shader, rendering, raymarching

I am working on a project for a client and I am trying to replicate the 3D volume rendering done in the Unity Inspector so I can view changes to 3D volume data in real-time.
Here is an example of what the final output should look like (with and without transparency):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtVbv.jpg
However, when I render this in real-time using a slightly modified version of the default Raymarching shader provided by Unity - my results are quite different.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2YA.jpg
Here is the shader code being used to render the 3D texture:

```
 Shader "Unlit/3DVolumeShader"
 {
 Properties
 {
     _Alpha ("Alpha", float) = 0.8
     _StepSize ("Step Size", float) = 0.01
 }
 SubShader
 {
     Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
     Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
     LOD 100

     Pass
     {
         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag

         #include "UnityCG.cginc"

         #define TEX_WIDTH 512
         #define TEX_HEIGHT 64
         #define TEX_LENGTH 384

         // Maximum amount of raymarching samples
         #define MAX_STEP_COUNT 128

         // Allowed floating point inaccuracy for hit detection
         #define EPSILON 0.00001f

         struct appdata
         {
             float4 vertex : POSITION;
         };

         struct v2f
         {
             float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
             float3 objectVertex : TEXCOORD0;
             float3 vectorToSurface : TEXCOORD1;
         };

         float _Alpha;
         float _StepSize;

         StructuredBuffer<float4> DensityMap;
         
         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
             v2f o;

             // Vertex in object space this will be the starting point of raymarching
             o.objectVertex = v.vertex;

             // Convert vertex in object space to camera coordinates
             o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

             // Calculate vector from camera to vertex in world space
             float3 worldVertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
             o.vectorToSurface = worldVertex - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

             return o;
         }

         // This method blends colors based on their alpha transparency
         // If color.a == 1 then no blending will occur
         // Otherwise multiply the difference in the alpha's by the new color
         float4 BlendColors(float4 color, float4 newColor)
         {
             color.rgb += (1.0 - color.a) * newColor.a * newColor.rgb;
             color.a += (1.0 - color.a) * newColor.a;
             return color;
         }

         fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
         {
             // Start raymarching at the front surface of the object
             float3 rayOrigin = i.objectVertex;

             // Use vector from camera to object surface to get the ray direction
             float3 rayDirection = mul(unity_WorldToObject, float4(normalize(i.vectorToSurface), 1));

             float4 color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);

             float3 bounds = float3(TEX_WIDTH, TEX_LENGTH, TEX_HEIGHT);
             float3 samplePosition = rayOrigin;

             // Raymarch through object space
             for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEP_COUNT; i++)
             {
                 // Accumulate color only within unit cube bounds
                 if(max(abs(samplePosition.x), max(abs(samplePosition.y), abs(samplePosition.z))) < 0.5f + EPSILON)
                 {
                     // Sample the color at the position in our density map. Add an offset for UV coordinate transformation.
                     // float4 sampledColor = tex3D(_DensityMap, samplePosition + float3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

                     float3 textureCoord = (samplePosition + float3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)) * bounds;
                     int index = int(textureCoord.x) + (int(textureCoord.y) * bounds.x) + (int(textureCoord.z) * bounds.x * bounds.y);

                     float4 sampledColor = DensityMap[index];
                     sampledColor.a *= _Alpha;

                     // Blend the colors based on alpha transparency
                     color = BlendColors(color, sampledColor);

                     samplePosition += rayDirection * _StepSize;
                 }
             }

             return color;
         }
         ENDCG
     }
 }
 }
```

I am using raymarching to index into the 3D texture array, which is where I think this issue might be occurring. I'm wondering if I might have something wrong with the scaling/coordinate system that Unity uses.
My texture size is 512x64x384 and I am rendering to a cube with scaling 1x0.1x0.75.
Please let me know if there is any additional information required to solve this.